# Responsive side by side images

Tags: html, css, image, shopify, responsive

Im trying to create a responsive layout in a shopify theme that looks like: http://postimg.org/image/7r6jo647l/. I've tried everything and cannot get the desired result. I'm turning to the brighter minds on reddit for help. Any help at all would be appreciated, i named the image frustrating.jpg which pretty much says it all :-/

I'm not looking for someone to do the grunt work, just point me in the right direction...before i go bald tearing my hair out.

Comment: I don't understand. Is that your page or an example of what you want.

Comment: "I've tried everything..." Then why didn't you show anything?

Comment: Sorry my fault, im new and should have added in my code i was working, on, i will do that now.

Comment: I was able to get this together: jsfiddle.net/5cripted/0suzr1ze/1. Whenever it is sized down the margin goes weird on the right, and i cant get the just arrived to overlap over the images below. I tried z-index, but i think it only works on absolute positioning.

Answer (score 0):

that is easy with Bootstrap - the following will create 4 adjacent divs for the images - these will stack horizontally in a single row of 4 on medium to large size sceens, two rows of two adjacent images on small screens and will stack vertically on mobile (xs) screens.

//row of 4 adjacent images

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
      <img src="smallImage-1.jpg" alt="Small Image1">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
      <img src="smallImage-2.jpg" alt="Small Image2">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
      <img src="smallImage-3.jpg" alt="Small Image3">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
      <img src="smallImage-4.jpg" alt="Small Image5">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your theme needs to accommodate a variable number of images use css to manage this:

A minimal set of display:flex display:table for the image wrapper

A fiddle with flex is at:

https://jsfiddle.net/xma6kbxa/

```css
.wrap, .wrap *{
 box-sizing:border-box;
}

.wrap{
  display:flex;
  margin-left:-5px;
  margin-right:-5px;
  clear:left;
  width:100%;
  border:1px solid blue;
 }
 .wrap .holder{
   margin:5px;
   }
  .wrap img{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
  }
 }
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
<div class="holder"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></div>
<div class="holder"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></div>
<div class="holder"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></div>
<div class="holder"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></div>
</div>

<div class="wrap">
<div class="holder"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></div>
<div class="holder"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></div>
<div class="holder"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></div>
```

Note FWIW basic flex support is pretty wide. http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, i was able to get this together: https://jsfiddle.net/5cripted/0suzr1ze/1/. Whenever it is sized down the margin goes weird on the right, and i cant get the just arrived to overlap over the images below. I tried z-index, but i think it only works on absolute positioning.

Comment: This is what happens when i make the browser smaller: http://postimg.org/image/rvvgs1qxd/

Comment: Any sort of web layout work requires at least a basic understanding CSS and its capabilities and weaknesses. There are a million resources. I've re-worked your fiddle to be https://jsfiddle.net/bknights/0suzr1ze/5/ A great explanation of css flex is at https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/. The problem with the example I just provided is that it you don't get the full width effect unless your browser is perfectly sized. The way around this is with css media queries. Bootstrap could handle much of this but I find I often bypass bootstrap for header nav.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div width="100%" class="holder">
    <img width="49.5%" src="https://placehold.jp/750x500.png">
    <img width="49.5%" src="https://placehold.jp/750x500.png">
  </div>
</div>
```